# How to preseve the path when edge remved networkx graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I would like to keep the path when I filtered specific nodes within a networkx graph. 
let us say I have the following graph.

[image]

When I removed **node 20**, I would like to keep the path or connection with the next node, since there is a connection through node 20.

And I would like to have the following.

[image]

Can anyone out there help me to approach this challenge using python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a directed graph, you can get all edges incident to a node using `g.in_edges(node)`, and all outgoing edges with `g.out_edges(node)`.
Once you have these, it is a simple matter of connecting the sources from the incident edges and the targets from the outgoing edges.
An undirected graph doesn't have the concept of in-coming and out-going edges, so you just combine the neighbours (`g.neighbors`). 
Finally, you remove your node.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""
Remove a node from a network while maintaining all paths.
"""
import itertools
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def remove_node(g, node):
    if g.is_directed():
        sources = [source for source, _ in g.in_edges(node)]
        targets = [target for _, target in g.out_edges(node)]
    else:
        sources = g.neighbors(node)
        targets = g.neighbors(node)

    new_edges = itertools.product(sources, targets)
    new_edges = [(source, target) for source, target in new_edges if source != target] # remove self-loops
    g.add_edges_from(new_edges)

    g.remove_node(node)

    return g

if __name__ == '__main__':

    edges = [(10, 20), (20, 30), (30, 40)]
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    g.add_edges_from(edges)

    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
    nx.draw_networkx(g, with_labels=True, ax=ax1)

    g = remove_node(g, 20)

    nx.draw_networkx(g, with_labels=True, ax=ax2)
    plt.show()
```